# Why won't my command block chain work?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been working on a large multiplayer world. In it, I have set up a "P.A. System" using a command block chain, with all the blocks set to use the `/say` command to send messages in chat.

When I send a [Redstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Dust) signal through the chain, the first block (set to impulse, not chain, and unconditional) activates. Then the second block (set to chain and conditional) activates. The signal seems to end there, as the third block (set to chain and conditional) does not activate.
Why is this setup not working?

I am playing Bedrock Edition, on my phone.

Comment: All command blocks contain `/say` commands? Those should always succeed. Have you checked whether they are all rotated the right way and set to "always active" instead of "needs redstone"?

Comment: Oh, they need to be set to always active? Didnt know that. I'll change that when I get back on later and see if that works.

Comment: @Fabian Röling that worked, thank you! Can you please make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ummm… Alright… That's an extremely basic thing, but if you say so, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a command block says "needs redstone", it needs redstone. Otherwise it doesn't work. Either give it redstone (for example a lever) or set it to "always active".